# Unicode %uXXXX encoding/decoding XS module in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding

Is there any Perl XS module with high-speed subroutines suitable for encoding/decoding of the non-standard %uXXXX unicode characters found in unicode cookies (especially Firefox)?

decoding: input = ...%uXXXX... , output = a normal utf8 Perl string
encoding: input = a normal utf8 Perl string, output = ...%uXXXX...

Now I'm decoding these strings using this code:

```
    $string =~ s/%u([A-Fa-f0-9]{4})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
```

but it would be nice to have a C-implemented version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about two?

- [URI::Escape::XS](http://p3rl.org/URI%3a%3aEscape%3a%3aXS#Note-on-the-uHHHH-sequence)
- [CGI::Deurl::XS](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aDeurl%3a%3aXS)

---

[URL::Encode::XS](http://p3rl.org/URL%3a%3aEncode%3a%3aXS) also exists, but does not meet the requirement.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what is required. I was looking to URI::Escape, but didn't find in the docs about the %uxxxx encoding. The XS version seems to be more advanced. I'll be testing/benchmarking it and I'll come soon to mark this question as answered. Meanwhile, someone could also add other modules, if any. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, the URI::Escape::XS module is doing encoding/decoding as required, but unfortunately it operates 10 times slower than the pure Perl regex substitution.

Answer (score 3):

This particular format is not related to cookies in itself, but is one of the common forms of ad-hoc encoding applied to cookies. It is generated by the JavaScript function `escape()`. It looks a lot like URL-encoding, but it isn't compatible; JS authors really need to stop using it.

[URI::Escape::JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/~taniguchi/URI-Escape-JavaScript-0.04/lib/URI/Escape/JavaScript.pm)  has an implementation that reproduces the `unescape` algorithm. It's basically the same approach as yours, but also handles the two-digit `%xx` pattern.

Modules that try to treat JS-escape encoding as an extension of URL-encoding are likely to trip on the potentially different handling of the `+` character.

I doubt any application will spend enough of its time decoding these to make it worth doing in C, really.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's not related only to cookies. The problem is that Firefox likes to use this encoding (Chrome encodes unicode directly as escaped bytes). In my case two-digit %xx codes are automatically decoded by Apache::Cookie::fetch(), so I have to handle the %uxxxx cases. Anywaym thank you for your note and shared experience.

Comment: Firefox does not do escaping on cookies by itself, only (like other browsers) when `escape()` is explicitly called. Attempting to include raw non-ASCII characters in cookies will just break, not escape. Nonetheless, if you are using a standard URL-decoder to handle your `%xx` sequences you will probably get inconsistent results with the characters in the range U+0080–U+009F (because a URL-decoder will them to be UTF-8-encoded, but `escape()` produces ISO-8859-1-encoded bytes here), and the `+` issue.

Comment: Well, of course chances are high that I'm doing smth wrong, but at least Firefox and Chrome treat differently unicode in cookies names and values (and maybe in other places too). Probably `escape()` is called behind the scenes, but Firebug/Firecookie and the 'console' encode unicode using `%uxxxx`. I'm talking here about the default behaviour, while an explicit `encodeURI()` produces the standard percent-encoded code.

Comment: Test case? Setting `document.cookie='foo=a\u0101b'` (or via `Set-Cookie`) and then reading `document.cookie` back does not apply any `%u` encoding in Firefox or Chrome. There are differences in their handling of non-ASCII characters, to the extant that non-ASCII characters in cookies are basically unusable in any cross-browser context, but neither touches `escape()`. (In particular: Chrome and Opera interpret as UTF-8; Firefox uses the least significant byte of the UTF-16 code unit for each character; IE uses the ANSI code page; Safari refuses to set the cookie completely.)